# How to remove hyperlink using mootools based on its value?

Tags: mootools

In the code below how to remove the li based on the value of hyperlink?

```
<ul class="clean menu sub">
    <li>
        <a cat="tech" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_internet_fios" rel="1">FiOS Internet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a cat="tech" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_internet_hsi" rel="1">High Speed Internet</a>
    </li>
    <li class="last" style="margin-bottom:7px;">
        <a cat="tech" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_internet_dialup" rel="1">Dial-up</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I get the valu of the hyperlink in a variable. Now based on the value other 2 li's should be deleted. How can we achieve this using mootools?

Now if I get flag="Dial-up", Other 2 li's should be deleted and the code should look like this:

```
<ul class="clean menu sub">
    <li class="last" style="margin-bottom:7px;">
        <a cat="tech" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_internet_dialup" rel="1">Dial-up</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here I get the value of Flag from server.

Comment: Did you want to filter the links (and its parent li) based on the name attribute of the link or the text of the link? Have you tried any solution 'till now?

Comment: $("step-1").getElements('ul.menu a.sec_net_1 ').getParent().destroy();  I tried this but this deletes all the li's since all the anchor tags have same class...So I thought may be we can delete using anchor tag value.

Comment: As you said may be we can use name attribute. But how can we do it using name attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can leverage on link names the solution is a single line:

http://jsfiddle.net/5axJc/

```
$$("ul.menu :not(a[name='&li=choose_category_internet_dialup']) !> li").destroy()
```

calling destroy on a collection (I would have used document.getElements in production code) will call your method on every elements in it.

In the selection expression there are several *esoteric* selector and maybe it worth some deeper explanation:

- ul.menu is a plain class based selector
- :not(a[name='&li=choose_category_internet_dialup'])
  select links based on the `name` attributes that do `:not()` match the value
- !> is a parent selector

hence you can read the selector as:

select all the li into the menu ul that are father of an anchor whose name is NOT your desired value.

**EDIT**

To select only the li that are parents of the searched one just select it with 
`ul.sub a[name='&lid=choose_category_internet_fios'] !> li` and based on that
select all siblings with `~ li`. the result is like this.

```
$$("ul.sub a[name='&lid=choose_category_internet_fios'] !> li ~ li").dispose()
```

Note we have get rid of the :not() selector. To me it is a more linear way to accomplish the task.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5axJc/3/ . I have updated my list here...Now if I use your line of solution here, its removing the list from all the UL's. Here other lists should remain same. Only the list in which "Dialup" is present should be updated. Any suggestion for this? Please help..

Comment: It is a little unpleasant to read css in comments, I've updated my answer

Comment: You are really genious!! Thanks for the answer :)